# Pandas : How to align/center a date column & aggregate other column on either direction of the date?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

How to align/center date-column of a dataframe (and its assoicated rows) based on an event (another column value).

Explaining with example:
I have a data frame as below.

What I'm trying to do is the *center the date column* based on `event` column. In this case `3/12/12` is the center.

Then I need the average of values from `center - 2months` (21) and `center + 2months` (30.5)

```
df=pd.DataFrame([
        ['1/10/12',No, 20],
        ['2/11/12',No, 22],
        ['3/12/12',Yes, 29],
        ['4/14/12',No, 30],
        ['5/14/12',No, 31]
        ],
        columns=['Time', 'event', 'value'])
```

In the above case the resulting dataframe will be:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([
        ['pre_center', 20],
        ['center', 22],
        ['post_center', 30.5]
        ],
        columns=['Range', 'average_value'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
# convert to datetime
s = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

# identify the center
center = s[df['event'].eq('Yes')].iloc[0]

# identify if the date is before/center/after
group = (np.sign(s.sub(center).dt.days.astype(int))
           .map({-1: 'pre_center', 0: 'center', 1: 'post_center'})
        )

# aggregate
out = df.groupby(group)['value'].agg(average_value='sum')
```

Output:

```
         Range  average_value
0       center             29
1  post_center             61
2   pre_center             42
```

If you want to include a threshold:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

center = s[df['event'].eq('Yes')].iloc[0]

diff = pd.DateOffset(months=2)
m1 = s.between(center-diff, center)
m2 = s.between(center, center+diff)
group = np.select([m1&m2, m1, m2], ['center', 'pre_center', 'post_center'], np.nan)

out = (df.groupby(group)['value']
         .agg(average_value='sum')
         .drop('nan', errors='ignore')
         .rename_axis('Range').reset_index()
      )
```

Output:

```
         Range  average_value
0       center             29
1  post_center             30
2   pre_center             22
```

Comment: I get the error "cannot astype a datetimelike from [timedelta64[ns]] to [int32]"

Comment: thanks @jezrael and @mozway ! @jezrael, I dont see a difference between ```threshold``` and ```center```. Where would that be beneficial ?

Comment: @Salih that was to be removed, sorry, the threshold is actually `diff`